# Voltage rating of snubber circuit

Tags: solid-state-relay, snubber

I am referring a solid state relay circuit from [here](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/97984.pdf). The circuit given is below[image]

Well I'm new to this, so dam confused with voltage rating of resistance and capacitance of snubber circuit. what would be the voltage ratting of components when connecting this at 220 ac volt.

Please help,how can I decide this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way would be: 220VAC = 308Vpk. So the capacitor has to be at least that, and probably higher too since the voltage when switching an inductor is going to spike higher than that. You can use 1/2LI^2 to figure out how much the inductor is going to try and dump in to the cap see what it  will charge up to.

Comment: is this same apply for 360, 470 ohm and 0.05uf capacitor ?

Comment: @Abhishekbhatia Yes, since when the capacitor not charged the resistor sees the full voltage, and when the capacitor is fully charged the cap sees the full voltage.